# Точная копия стиля кнопки Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

Здравствуйте. Мне необходимо сделать вот такие кнопки. Пытался и ImageButton использовать и простой Button, в итоге получалось следующее (см. 3 рисунок).
Мой код:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/autorenew"
                android:drawablePadding="0dp"
                android:text="Check Now"
                />



            <Button
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/play"
                android:drawablePadding="0dp"
                android:text="Start serv"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/stop"
                android:drawablePadding="0dp"
                android:text="Stop service"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Но это не очень похоже на то, что мне нужно... Ripple эффект даже не такой и ограничивается его радиус.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `TextView` вместо `Button` и бекграунд у них `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`, вместо стиля.

Comment: Выглядит несомненно лучше, но слева и справа Ripple эффект ограничивается прямыми границами. Хотелось бы как в примере, что бы был как круг.

Comment: http://ibb.co/f1ihWS вот такой результат

Comment: А так `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`?

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо) Один вопрос, как можно пониже картинку опустить?

Comment: Может у вас есть отступы в самой картинке? Прозрачная область. Потому что при `drawablePadding="0dp"` не должно быть таких отступов. И высоту попробуйте сделать `wrap_content`

Comment: Нужно использовать BottomNavigation - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

Answer (score 1):

Для начала создайте .xml файл в ваших drawable ресурсах.
Нужный вам путь: res/drawable/ripple_effect.xml

Поместите в него этот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:color="#80000000"
tools:targetApi="lollipop">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#f8a7a9a8" />
        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</ripple>
```

После чего добавьте тэг android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect" в xml файл с кнопкой.

Пример:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
android:padding="16dp"
android:text="New Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Решение проблемы (спасибо eugeneek):**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/autorenew"
                android:text="Check Now"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                />



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/play"
                android:text="Start service"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/stop"
                android:text="Stop service"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```